# save and read non-aggregate Roots

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i'm a beginner in Spring data jpa. I learned from the docs that we create repositories for aggregate roots only. for example an object **Order** encapsulates operations on multiple **LineItem** objects. The **Order** contains the **LineItem** objects. so **Order** is the aggregate root, for which a repository will be created.

the we can save, read **Order** objects easily using, repository methods:

```
OrderRepository.save(order)
OrderRepository.findAll
```

My question is, if I want to create **Lineitem** objects before **Order** objects to store them in a combobox , how can I save them if I can't create repository for them?

Or if I want simply to just show the list of **Lineitems** how can I read the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Items that exists before Orders, this means only one thing: Orders and Items are two different aggregate roots, hence they could be handled in different ways. So this solves your problem: you need two Repositories, one for Orders and one for Items. In every other context where you handle Items inside Orders the formrrs cannot exist before latters. 
This, anyway, needs a bit of work on the save, because you've to check for every Order if an Item in added/removed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we have a model:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    private Long id;    

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList();    

    public Order(Item... items) {

        items.addAll(Arrays.asList(items)  ;
    }

    //...
}

@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //...
}
```

To save items that belong to the Order we do the following:

```
Item item1 = new Item();
Item item2 = new Item();
Order order = new Order(item1, item2);
orderRepo.save(order);
```

Because we used `cascade = ALL` for `items` they will be saved together with Order.
The same will work for other operations: update, delete...

**UPDATE**

If the model assumes an independent work with entities (for example: list of item categories) then we should create a repository for them that allow us to store entities separately from other AR.

```
public interface ItemRepo extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
}

Item item1 = new Item();
Item item2 = new Item();
itemRepo.save(asList(item1, item2);
Order order = new Order(item1, item2);
orderRepo.save(order);
```

But I think that it's not the best choice for order items cause they cannot live without Order.

Comment: yes but let's suppose I have a ready list of items, i will need to save them first then choose the appropriate item for the order. how can I do that?

Comment: @siraf123 why do you need to save it first? If you are going to operate with independent entities you have to create and use a repo for them. But I think that it's not the best choice for order lines...

Comment: for example if I have two entities : Person and Country, I 'll create repository for person , but countries are known i will have to save them first, otherwise there will be repetition. I might add two persons in the same country, in the database the table country will contain the same country twice.

Comment: @siraf123 Country and Person are independent entities. They both should have repos. See my updated answer..

Comment: thank you! so i will have to create repos for both of them.  i don't understand why you said Country and Person are independent entities. to create a Person i WILL  HAVE to enter its Country, so it depends on Country. it's a Many To One relationship.

Comment: Person and Country are 'independent' cause they can 'live' without each other. This is like a criterion to determine an AR. ))   (Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you...)